# using python to add images to powerpoint files

Tags: python, windows, powerpoint

has anyone used python to add images to powerpoint 2007 files? can someone please help me get started with this

Comment: Are these presentation you are generating yourself, or are you wanting to modify existing files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with Office's COM/OLE [automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303717) API.  For example, see this post:

- [Automating PowerPoint with Python](http://www.s-anand.net/blog/automating-powerpoint-with-python/)